Unable to run POST(/signup) in postman
index.js
import express from "express"
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import bodyParser from "body-parser"

import path from "path"
import { fileURLToPath } from "url"

import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.route.js"
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.route.js"
import expenseRoutes from "./routes/expense.route.js"

import { signup } from "./controllers/authe.controller.js"

//CONFIGURATIONS
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

const app = express()

//CONFIGURATIONS
dotenv.config()
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }))

//middlewares
app.use(express.json)

//DATABASE
const port = process.env.PORT | 6001
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL)

//ROUTES
app.use("/auth", authRoutes)
app.use("/user", userRoutes)
app.use("/expense", expenseRoutes)

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`))

auth.route.js
import express from "express"
import { signin, signup } from "../controllers/authe.controller.js"

const router = express.Router()

router.post("/signup", signup)
router.get("/signin", signin)

export default router

authe.controller.js
import bcrypt from "bcrypt"
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken"
import User from "../models/user.model.js"

//REGISTER USER
export const signup = async (req,res) => {
    try{

        console.log(req.body)
        const {
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password
        } = req.body

        const salt =  await bcrypt.genSalt()
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)

        const newUser = new User({
            firstName,
            lastName,
            email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })

        const savedUser = await newUser.save()
        res.status(process.env.CREATED).json(savedUser)

    }catch(err){
        res.status(process.env.INGTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({error: err.message})
        }
}

I'm struck here for a long time, can somebody help me figure out what's wrong?
If you need anything else let me know.
I tried running on postman using http://localhost:3002/signup
But it is always showing sending request screen.
I tried running only the signup logic by copying in another file and it's working.

Try using curl instead of Postman to begin with.
